# 2D Unity - Platformer - Stuck on Fall Transition Animation in Animator

Tags: 2d, sprite, transition, animator

I'm trying to make a prototype for my interactive media class but I hit a little hiccup on the progress. I was following a tutorial where everything was running smoothly till I got to using the Animator. I followed every instruction step by step during the tutorial I was watching. Basically, my 2D Sprite Character is stuck in the fall animation whenever I play the game rather than it being in the default idle animation like it's supposed to be. I tried deleting and recreating the animation paths but that didn't work. I even tried deleting everything and putting everything in from scratch back into the animator. I did check off exit time, set the duration for zero, and give the "state" which is what I called the in their respective numbers but it's still stuck on falling. when I jump with my character the run and idle animation seem to be working. It's like everything reversed with falling. It also gave me the difference in effective length is too big as an error. I tried adding more frames to my falling animation to see if that would fix and also tried checking and unchecking loop time and It's still stuck on the fall. If anyone knows what's wrong with the animator please let me know. I don't think it has anything to do with the code but better safe than sorry so I'll put it here. If anyone has the answer to my issue please get back to me when you can and thank you!

PlayerMovement.cs: `

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite; 
    private Animator anim;

    private float dirX = 0f;
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 12f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 16f;

    private enum MovementState { idle, running, jumping, falling }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }

        UpdateAnimationState(); 
    }

    private void UpdateAnimationState()
    {
        MovementState state;

        if (dirX > 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.running; 
            sprite.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (dirX < 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.running;
            sprite.flipX = true;
        }
        else
        {
            state = MovementState.idle;
        }

        if (rb.velocity.y > .1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.jumping; 
        }
        else if (rb.velocity.y > -.1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.falling;
        }

        anim.SetInteger("state", (int)state);
    }
}
```

[This is my Animator in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTCJN.png)

[The Player Falling Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plrl7.png)

[Player Running -> Player Falling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC8Pp.png)

[Player Idle -> Player Falling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iec5V.png)

[Player Jumping -> Player Falling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zZvT.png)

Comment: Can you share a screen shot of your animator tab . maybe the inspector too so we can help you